# detect editButtonItem tap

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UITableView with an editButtonItem in the navigation bar. I wanted to have a tap sound play whenever the user taps the editButtonItem. Right now, I'm using the following method to play the tap sound when edit button is tapped

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
//Code to play the tap sound file
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];}
```

But the problem I have is that the tap sound also plays when user swipes a tableviewcell & the delete button shows up, which is not something I want. So, my question is, is there a better way to detect when the editButtonItem is tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will play a sound **ONLY** when the edit button is tapped. When you tap **Done** it will not play a sound. Also, when you swipe a cell, the sound should not play.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {
        swipedToDelete = YES; // BOOL ivar
    }
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing && !swipedToDelete) 
    {
        // Play sound
    }

    if (swipedToDelete) {
        swipedToDelete = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will still play the sound when I swipe a tableviewcell & the delete button shows up. Which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense, and I can see why it should work, but, for some reason, the sound still plays when swiping a cell. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1542795 add some NSLogs in the set editing to output the `swipedToDelete` value. Also add some NSLog to the `willTransitionToState` to see which one is getting called first.

Comment: Was about to start banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why willTransitionToState was not being called at all, when I realised that willTransitionToState is a method on UITableViewCell not UITableViewController. Thanks!!